# Realm database Java: How to read from RealmResult without knowing Type at compile time?

Tags: java, realm

We have generic method for reading results from realm database. So at compile time we do not know which objects are going to be retrieved.

`RealmResult` now contains a `RealmProxy` with column names and index numbers for the correct objects (so generic query seems to work fine), but how to get the real data from the proxy?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you want to read fields and use methods from the generated proxies of your model classes?

Comment: We use reflection to find out the class we want to retrieve => `classname`. Then we use `RealmResults result = query.where(classname).findAll();`
Now we want to read `RealmResults` in a loop and retrieve Content of the fields also via reflection. But all we get are fields with `INDEX_` prefix in the field name and index numbers or something like that as content. We need the 'real' content e.g. Strings and Dates...

Comment: Well, using reflection is one way of course, but those operations are extremely slow, especially on Android. Another option could be to use our dynamic interface, which right now is only exposed for migrations. Did you take a look to that yet?

Comment: Do you mean the `RealmMigration` Interface and getting tables from the realm instead of objects? I haven't tried it yet, but I will take a look into it.

Comment: I tried it now and have the problem retrieving the table row number of the object in my RealmResult. How do I get it? Or maybe I did not get your idea?

Comment: I'm afraid what you are trying to do is very complicated and almost impossible to achieve without prior knowledge of our core and its internals.
If you look in the RealmResults class you will see a reference to a TableView class. That's what you want to explore to achieve what you need.